# Индексируются ли статьи ВКонтакте поисковиками Google и Yandex?

Tags: вконтакте, seo, поисковые-системы

Можно ли в поиске Google или Yandex найти статью ВКонтакте с URL вида

```
https://vk.com/@...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нет. Эти страницы генерируются **виджетами** на лету.

Answer (score 1):

Всё отлично индексируется.
И заголовок, и сам текст.

Вот пример: https://vk.com/@nko_spk-priglashaem-prinyat-uchastie-v-rabote-konferencii-maloe-pred

Выдача Google:

[image: Индексация Google]

Выдача Yandex:

[image: Индексация Yandex]